# combine multiple RSS feed with manual selection

Tags: html, rss, feed, rssi

I want to receive multiple `RSS` `feed` and select the item that I want to push into one custom `RSS` `feed`.

There are websites that allows you to put multiple `feeds` in one, but I want to have a treatment in addition, I want to `select` the `feed` `item` that I want to put out.

if it doesn't exist, I think I want to make a `HTML5/JS` webapplication but I don't know how store `RSS items` to put in `OUT` `RSS`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use jquery script to achieve what you want: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex18/gajaxrssdisplayer.htm

You just need to put the jquery into the folder with your page and put in the rss feed into your html code accordingly. This script allows multiple rss feed and a lot of customization to display the feeds.